# Does the MacBook Pro built-in screens support HDR?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, hdr

On [this Apple support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210980), it seems to say that the MacBook Pro introduced in 2018 or 2019 supports HDR on its built-in display. However, for what I understand, MacBook screens are not bright enough to support HDR. I also have not seen any HDR settings on my 2020 MacBook Pro, nor is HDR touted in Apple's computer specs.

Do MacBook screens support HDR?

Comment: No.  See this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/318002/119271. It’s technically correct (though someone didn’t like it).  Basically, if it doesn’t say HDR, it’s not HDR.

Comment: Hmm, still a bit confused here. From what I understand, the newer Macs (2018+) *can* drive displays with HDR. And it's still unclear to me if the internal display of these Macs have HDR? The Apple support article linked seems to say that it is capable

Comment: “Seems to say” is the operative language here.  They are dancing around it and getting you to believe it supports it.  HDR is not trademarked so, why obfuscate it?  It doesn’t meet the Rec 2020 spec which defines HDR, so they can’t say that it supports it.

Comment: @Allan I see, so it kind of does but not up to the official spec. Honestly, this could be an answer to my question (unless you want me to post to skeptics)

Comment: Exactly.  “It kinda does” but they prefer their customers to reference everything as “Retina.”

Comment: What a bummer! Because their own web page https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210980 states that "Mac models that support HDR" on "Built-in
display" and "MacBook Pro introduced in 2018 or later".

Answer (score 0):

No, not yet. Maybe someday. I'm really looking forward to that day. Hopefully it is the same day that the MacBook Air supports HDR.